# Saving JS nested array from localStorage to MySQL table using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, local-storage

I am pushing arrays to localStorage which I want to store in a MySQL table upon clicking a button.

```
var coords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coords'));
```

the var coords provides me with the following output:

```
["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg", "PerimeterBoard", "Jupiter", 236, 353, 292, 319, 312, 362, "STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg", "TShirt", "Redshift", 268, 410, 381, 398, 381, 469, "STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg", "Mic", "Airtel", 317, 327, 425, 329, 421, 371, "STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg", "Mic", "Airtel", 575, 300, 575, 300, 626, 282]
```

I am using the following function to push this array to a PHP file:

```
function dbSave(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var coords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coords'));
   $.post("saveAnnotations.php", {'data' : coords }, function(output){
      alert(output);
      });
}
```

**saveAnnotations.php**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$database);
$lsData = isset($_POST['data'])?$_POST['data']:'';
$annArray = json_decode($lsData, true);

$image = $annArray[0];
$location = $annArray[1];
$brand = $annArray[2];
$firstX = $annArray[3];
$firstY = $annArray[4];
$secondX = $annArray[5];
$secondY = $annArray[6];
$thirdX = $annArray[7];
$thirdY = $annArray[8];

$sql = "INSERT into `annotations` (`matchName`, `imagename`, `locationName`, `brandname`, `firstx`, `firsty`, `secondx`,`secondy`, `thirdx`,`thirdy`) values 
        ('$matdir','$image', '$location','$brand','$firstX','$firstY','$secondX','$secondY','$thirdX','$thirdY');";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
if ($result) {
    echo "Data uploaded Successfully";
}
$connect->close();

?>
```

The connection to the MySQL Db and table is perfect. When I hardcoded the values of each one of the fields, the data gets updated into the table.   I think the problem is with posting the array from localStorage to PHP and decoding the same at PHP end.

```
$annArray = json_decode(json_encode($lsData, true), true);
$countArray = count($annArray);
$interval = $countArray/9;


function fill_chunck($array, $parts) {
    $t = 0;
    $result = array_fill(0, $parts - 1, array());
    $max = ceil(count($array) / $parts);
    foreach($array as $v) {
        count($result[$t]) >= $max and $t ++;
        $result[$t][] = $v;
    }
    return $result;
}

//echo print_r(fill_chunck($annArray, $interval));
$inputArray = [];
$inputArray = fill_chunck($annArray, $interval);

foreach($inputArray as $value=>$data) {
    $image = $data[0];
    $location = $data[1];
    $brand = $data[2];
    $firstX = $data[3];
    $firstY = $data[4];
    $secondX = $data[5];
    $secondY = $data[6];
    $thirdX = $data[7];
    $thirdY = $data[8];

    $sql = "INSERT into `annotations` (`imagename`, `locationName`, `brandname`, `firstx`, `firsty`, `secondx`,`secondy`, `thirdx`,`thirdy`) values 
        ('$image', '$location','$brand','$firstX','$firstY','$secondX','$secondY','$thirdX','$thirdY');";


    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    if ($result) {
        echo "Data uploaded Successfully";
    }
    $connect->close();


}
```

Comment: can you try to escape values in query ?

Comment: what is the value of  $annArray ?

Comment: @NarayanSharma The value of annArray is blank and the value of `$lsData` is `Array` and not the data that I see for var coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one and paste output of $annArray

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$database);
$lsData = isset($_POST['data'])?$_POST['data']:'';
$annArray = json_decode(json_encode($lsData, true), true);
```

Comment: Thank you...the output of $annArray is `Array` - however when I tried to insert the $annArray into the database, I could insert the first array.  Do I have to use a forloop on $annArray?

Comment: Please paste whole output of $annArray. I know this is array but i need all the output. use echo '<pre>'; print_r($annArray);

Comment: The output of $annArray is as follows:  Array
(
    [0] => STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg
    [1] => PerimeterBoard
    [2] => Jupiter
    [3] => 236
    [4] => 353
    [5] => 292
    [6] => 319
    [7] => 312
    [8] => 362
    [9] => STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg
    [10] => TShirt
    [11] => Redshift
    [12] => 268
    [13] => 410
    [14] => 381
    [15] => 398
    [16] => 381
    [17] => 469

Comment: While the list is long...I have printed only the first two arrays...however the format and sequence is the same and the key values extend 71 which is the last value followed by a closing bracket `)`

Comment: This is single dimensional array. Tell me from where you want to split this data? in which multiple information  you want to store? you miss something here.

Comment: Index 0-8 is one array...9-17 is the next array...so the split should be every 9th array

Comment: Okay. Thats pretty simple. start foreach loop of $annArray and try to insert data inside that foreach. It will fix your problem.

Comment: But given array is single dimensional array. Please have a check. if you want to split single to multiple use array_chunk($annArray,8) it will convert it into multidimensional array. And loop through that array and insert inside loop.

Comment: @NarayanSharrma Since I do not know the length of the array, I have taken an interval and split the array...the result is an array split nicely into multiple arrays...however, when I run the for loop on the array, only the first array gets inserted and not the other...do you have any thoughts?  Have updated the codes to reflect the same

Comment: @NarayanSharma...Thank you...for all your help and guidance...I got it...The moment I moved the mysqli insert query out of the forloop it got inserted into the database.